# How to loop rows with PHP using GROUP_CONCAT MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am triyng to loop the products coming from different categories as shown below:

```
 $sql = query("SELECT c.name AS 'cat_name', c.image AS 'image', 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.title ORDER BY p.title DESC SEPARATOR ' ') AS 'product_name' 
                FROM products p 
                INNER JOIN categories c 
                ON p.category_id = c.id 
                GROUP BY p.category_id");
  confirm($sql);

  while($category = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $content = <<<DELIMITER


       <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <ul>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">{$category['cat_name']}</li>
                  <li><a title="Title" href="#">{$category['product_name']}</a></li>                    

                </ul>
              </li>



 DELIMITER;

 echo $content;
 }
```

The script above produces following result:

**Category name**
Product 1 Product 2...

I would like to have the products listed like this:
**Category name**
Product 1
Product 2
...

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Um, so don't use GROUP_CONCAT... GROUP BY

Answer (score 2):

The function `GROUP_CONCAT` with get you a response of only one line for each category. It will concatenate all your lines with the same category in only one.

You have two possibilities :

1. Using `GROUP_CONCAT` : each line will contain your Category with all your products concatenated. Then you should split the concatenation of your "Product name's list" to display them correctly.
2. Do not use `GROUP_CONCAT` : you group your result by the category name. In your loop, you check when the category name change and then change your html accordingly.

---

Edit:

Your variable `$category['product_name']` contains the names of your products concatenated by the function `GROUP_CONCAT` using the delimiter `space`.
If you write

```
echo $category['product_name']
```

it will print

```
Product 1 Product 2...
```

You can use `split()` (obsolete) or [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php) to separate the products names. And then, you will need to iterate over the array `explode()` returns to get each Product.

**But** if your products contains spaces in their names, using `GROUP_CONCAT` with space as delimiter and split with space as delimiter, you'll get too much results. I advise you tu use another delimiter that can't be use in the product name.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did not quite understand the poin 1: Then you should split the concatenation of your "Product name's list" to display them correctly. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: The field `product_name` of your query will contain the product names concatenated by a space. If you split your string by the concatenation character, you will get a set of elements. (Note that if your are using spaces in your product name, you will get much more products, hence you should choose an appropriate concatenation character like a pipe `|` or something else.

Comment: Yes, but the products are always displayed horizontally and not vertically as a list. I do not understand how to loop them as list (vertically)

Comment: @Robert `explode` would work. Just change the seperator for `GROUP_CONCAT` from `' '` to something that will never be in a product name (like `;`?) Than explode on product name in your while loop and loop through the resulting array

Answer (score 0):

You could use this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name cat_name
              , c.image
              , p.title product_name
           FROM products p   
           JOIN categories c 
             ON p.category_id = c.id;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly your suggestion  shows twice the category name